# Python program to calculate pi with the following sequence: pi = 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7......etc

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, pi, fractions

Just stuck on this problem and I've tried many ways but this is what I have so far. Not sure what's wrong with it.

```
def main(n):
    summ=0
    pipe=0
    for i in range(1, n, 4):
        x = 4/i
        summ = summ + x
    for j in range(3, n, 4):
        y = 4/j
        pipe = pipe + j
    ans = summ - pipe
    print(ans)
```

It's giving me crazy figures... don't see why:(

Comment: you're adding j to pipe, instead of y

Comment: I have downvoted that question for now until the code is properly formatted

Comment: Thanks guys I figured it out now a stupid error on my part, sorry.

Comment: As an aside, the following one-liner will also do it: `4 * sum((-1.)**(i//2) / i for i in range(1, 1000, 2))`

Answer (score 1):

```
    pipe = pipe + j
```

should be adding `y` instead. `j` is the loop variable, not what you want to be adding.

Answer (score 0):

There are more readable ways to code what you're doing; here's how I would do it.  Define the progression first, and then define the operations.  Have the function bail out when the object providing numbers runs out of numbers to provide.  You don't need to worry about keeping a `pipe` variable in this case, and you don't need to worry about making two different lists to hold the positive and negative subtractions.

```
def pi(n):
    ''' returns approximations of pi. '''
    result = 0
    odd_numbers = xgen(1, n, 2)
    while True:
        try:
            result += 4.0/odd_numbers.next()
            result -= 4.0/odd_numbers.next()
        except StopIteration:
            break
    return result

def xgen(start, stop, step):
    ''' turns an xrange into an actual generator. '''
    for i in xrange(start, stop, step):
        yield i
```

Comment: Is your `xgen` just a longwinded way of writing `iter(xrange(whatever))`?

Comment: You might be able to justify your "longwinded" generator by making it also alternate the sign of the yielded values and simplifying the `while` loop to only `result += 4.0/odd_numbers.next()`.

Comment: @DSM As evidenced by your one liner, there are significantly more elegant ways to write this function; the reason I posted this solution was to possibly introduce iterators and generator functions to someone who may not be aware of how or when to use them.  In that context, defining xgen 'the longwinded way' increases transparency into how an iterator works.  Learning about the `iter` function should come after that, no? :)

Comment: @martineau If the guy actually responds, I had intended to make an edit adding something to that effect-- ultimately refactoring both the `4.0/` and the sign alternation within the generator itself.

Comment: FWIW, I think what you're trying to do, and approach to doing so, is fine, but you really should have first answered the OP's question about their own code.

Comment: @martineau Ah, at the time of my response, he had already resolved the issue; hence the off topic answer.

Comment: @ernie an odd number raises `StopIteration` on the `result -= 4.0/odd_numbers.next()` line, bailing out of the loop the same way an even number would.  Or did you mean something else?